# Regex replace with empty string results in NULL characters in between

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, regex

Replacing a character with `regexp_replace` results in `NUL` characters in between.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(aColumn,'c', '')
INTO OUTFILE 'Replaced.csv';
```

for `abcd` results in:

```
ab d (infact: abNULd)
```

This does not occur with just `REPLACE`

using `MySQL 8`

Comment: For now the workaround is: an additional `REPLACE` of `CHAR(0)` with `''`

Comment: Please file a bug report at bugs.mysql.com.

Answer (score 2):

Ugh!  The plot thickens:

```
mysql> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd', 'c', '') = 'abd';
+-----------------------------------------+
| REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd', 'c', '') = 'abd' |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                                       1 |
+-----------------------------------------+

mysql> SELECT HEX(REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd', 'c', '')), HEX('abd');
+--------------------------------------+------------+
| HEX(REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd', 'c', '')) | HEX('abd') |
+--------------------------------------+------------+
| 610062006400                         | 616264     |
+--------------------------------------+------------+

mysql> SELECT LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd', 'c', '')), LENGTH('abd');
+-----------------------------------------+---------------+
| LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd', 'c', '')) | LENGTH('abd') |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------+
|                                       6 |             3 |
+-----------------------------------------+---------------+

mysql> SELECT @@version;
+-----------+
| @@version |
+-----------+
| 8.0.15    |
+-----------+
```

Looks like there are NULs all over!  And looks like they are ignored--somewhat!

I filed http://bugs.mysql.com/94203

MariaDB 10.3.11 "does the right thing"  ( 1 / no NULs / 3,3 )

Comment: [Regular Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html) *MySQL implements regular expression support using International Components for Unicode (ICU), which provides full Unicode support and is multibyte safe. (Prior to MySQL 8.0.4, MySQL used Henry Spencer's implementation of regular expressions, which operates in byte-wise fashion and is not multibyte safe.* Try to wrap REGEXP_REPLACE with CONVERT() using proper charset, for example, `SELECT HEX(CONVERT(REGEXP_REPLACE('abcd', 'c', '') USING latin1)), HEX('abd');`.

Comment: @Akina - Then my gripe is that it converts to `ucs2` (I guess) without converting back.  I don't have the energy tonight to come up with test cases that demonstrate that and/or that it makes any difference.

Comment: @RickJames You have laid it out much more neatly than I would have